# Manually adding a legend in ggplot -- how to use aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to produce a graph with a legend highlighting three colors. I am able to select the correct colors or create a legend that highlights the three colors but not both.

The following code produces a graph with a legend but the colors are wrong

```
sanc_plot <- ggplot(sanction_combined, aes(x = trade_average, y = partner_cinc)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log2') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log2', labels = scales::scientific) + geom_point(aes(color="grey"),  size = 1) + 
  geom_point(data = sanction_combined %>% filter(sanction_ongoing=="1"), aes(color="yellow"), alpha = .4, size =1) + 
  geom_point(data = sanction_combined %>% filter(sanction_initiation=="1"), aes(color="red"),  alpha = .7, size = 1) + 
  labs(x = "Log2 of Rolling Average of U.S. Trade with Partner", y = "Log2 of Partner Military Power", title = "Bilateral Trade Flows, Partner Military Power, and U.S. Sanctions")
```

[image: graph with legend but wrong colors]

The following code produces a graph without a legend but the colors are right.

```
sanc_plot <- ggplot(sanction_combined, aes(x = trade_average, y = partner_cinc)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log2') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log2', labels = scales::scientific) + geom_point(aes(color="grey"),  size = 1) + 
  geom_point(data = sanction_combined %>% filter(sanction_ongoing=="1"), aes(color="yellow"), alpha = .4, size =1) + 
  geom_point(data = sanction_combined %>% filter(sanction_initiation=="1"), aes(color="red"),  alpha = .7, size = 1) + 
  labs(x = "Log2 of Rolling Average of U.S. Trade with Partner", y = "Log2 of Partner Military Power", title = "Bilateral Trade Flows, Partner Military Power, and U.S. Sanctions")
```

[image: graph with correct colors but no legend]

I have tried passing "scale_color_manual()" a vector with my prefered colors and labels, but it doesn't seem to do anything? I'm not sure why.

```
colors <- c("No Sanction" = "Grey", "New Sanction Initiation" = "red", "Ongoing Sanction" = "yellow")

sanc_plot <- ggplot(sanction_combined, aes(x = trade_average, y = partner_cinc)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log2') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log2', labels = scales::scientific) + geom_point(size = 1, color="grey") + 
  geom_point(data = sanction_combined %>% filter(sanction_ongoing=="1"), color="yellow", alpha = .4, size =1) + 
  geom_point(data = sanction_combined %>% filter(sanction_initiation=="1"), color="red",  alpha = .7, size = 1) + 
  labs(x = "Log2 of Rolling Average of U.S. Trade with Partner", y = "Log2 of Partner Military Power", title = "Bilateral Trade Flows, Partner Military Power, and U.S. Sanctions") + scale_color_manual(values = colors)
```

[image: attempt with scale_color_manual()]

I imagine I am misunderstanding something about how scale_color_manual() should work but I am somewhat stumped.

Comment: When you use `color="grey"` inside `aes()` ggplot2 will interpret this as a category with name`"grey"` not as a color. As a result ggplot2 will picks it's default colors. To get the colors corresponding to the labels you could do `+ scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")`.

Comment: A second option would be to use a manual scale and assign colors to the category names, i.e. do `scale_color_manual(values = c(grey = "grey", ...))` which will now assign the color `"grey"` to the category `"grey"`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. When I add + scale_color_identity(guide = "legend"), I have the legend with the correct colors but not the correct labels. It just lists "grey" "red" and "yellow." When I try to rename the color within aes() to a category name I the following error: "Error: Unknown colour name." How can I get the correct legend labels?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding ```+ scale_color_identity("Legend", guide = "legend", labels = c("No Sanction", "New Sanction", "Ongoing Sanction"))```